# How to match EOF (Ctrl-Z) in php

Tags: php

I need to accept inputs from keyboard in php. When the user is done with all the inputs he sends EOF (Ctrl-Z) .

How do I match this in php, so that the inputs can be processed and script still continues to execute.

Regards
Mithun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`feof()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.feof.php) on `php://stdin` opened as a file.